# css animation Spritesheet responsive issue

Tags: css, sprite-sheet

I have a animation sprite-sheet which works perfectly fine when it's dimensions are set with pixels,

but when the dimensions are set, either in percents or in vh it stopps working.
anyone faced this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/qya15v3v/1/

```
.responsive, .static{
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
.responsive{
    width:25vh;
    height:25vh;
}
```

Comment: I think you should make bigger or smaller your animation with different pictures to all sizes of screen

Comment: how would that be responsive?

Comment: Since your sprite itself is adapting to the container height, and you are manipulating the horizontal `background-position` to display different parts of your sprite, I’d say you have to change the values you are using for the position from pixels to some “responsive” value as well. (Although, for the second example, where the width is dynamic [25%], but the height static [200px], that will likely not work either. I think you will have to go “fully dynamic” in such cases, so that the ratio between width and height stays the same.)

Comment: @MoLow It would be responsive with `@media` and for example you will test a smartphone which have 480px in width, so for this resolution you should draw an image which `width` is 460px for example, and add margin from left and right near about 10px from every side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using the following

```
@keyframes flag {
    from {background-position: 0 top;}
    to {background-position: 800% top;} /*this is the number of steps multiplied by 100%*/
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qya15v3v/6/)

You will notice I have changed the percentage square so that it remains a square (use padding instead of height)

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this one:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/qya15v3v/7/)

```
@keyframes flag {
    from {background-position: 0 top;}
    to {background-position: 800% top;}
}
```